# Hunting or normal spears for hunting low level creatures

Tags: tibia

What's the most cost effective for hunting with a paladin in Tibia? I often hunt in the Venore Salamander cave to the west of the south exit. I'm currently using normal spears, but  would it be better to use hunting spears when it comes to cost and speed of gaining experience?

Answer (score 2):

Been out of the game for a while, but if you can't buy it from an NPC or craft it yourself, then it's probably going to end up to be to expensive.

You can keep an eye on trade and see if you can't find some hunting spears at cheap price (i.e. same price as a regular spear would be) and buy those, but just consider that an extra.
Best is to just level with normal spears, royal spear and enchanted spears later on (in terms of spears).
Arrow are also good to level on at low level, but you lose the benefit of a shield then.

If money is not an issue for you and your only goal is to power game, then you would probably be best off with bolts or arrows from NPCs

Answer (score 2):

1. First, Hunting Spears are breaking faster normal spear.
2. Try to use Royal Spears.They have more atack and harder to break.Also they are not expensive(15 gold at NPCs).